# Mapping a subdirectory to a second domain using hostgator?

Tags: wordpress, multiple-domains, subdirectory

I currently have all of my site hosting routed through my site `www.iamkuhan.com`, but I want one of my subdirectories, `iamkuhan.com/raindelay` to map to www.raindelaypodcast.com. I feel like this is pretty basic, but I can't find a good solution anywhere.

I know this can be done because I had someone else do it for me for `www.sentairangers.com`, which is found in the subdirectory `/sentairangers.com` of `iamkuhan.com`

All sites run Wordpress and are hosted with hostgator.

Answer (score 1):

Create an .htaccess file in the root directory of `www.iamkuhan.com` and put in it:

```
Redirect 301 /raindelay http://raindelaypodcast.com
```